# What is the VERSIONING_COMMITTING wait type in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have a fairly large SQL Server 2012 database in an availability group that experienced performance problems for about an hour, with the bulk of the wait in `HADR_SYNC_COMMIT` (waiting for synchronous replicas to commit) and `VERSIONING_COMMITTING`.

What does the `VERSIONING_COMMITTING` wait type signify?

Comment: Is your AG set to synchronous?

Comment: Yes, the AG is synchronous (there's also an async node in another data center)

Comment: I am not sure if you'll know this or not, but are any of the clients using snapshot isolation? Is SI enabled for any of the databases? RCSI?

Comment: It sounds like wait in `HARD_SYNC_COMMIT` would be your logs hardening with your secondary DB  to synchronize transactions, and the `VERSIONING_COMMITTING` is those locked records from those transactions in your setup being committed. Here's a good read on [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx#Lock_Basics)

Comment: I'm asking if your connection to primary are using them. Yes, RC is automatically mapped to SI on readable secondary replicas.

Comment: Can you also share the output of sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states? Specifically the availability replica id, and low watermark for ghosts?

Comment: @SeanGallardy yes, we have RCSI enabled, and allow snapshot isolation. Some of our workload utilises snapshot isolated transactions.

Comment: Then what I am looking at makes some sense. It seems the only place this wait type is encountered is checking for ghost records that are required for the version store. Don't 100% quote me on this but it's definitely something with the versioning and ghost records.

Comment: It looks benign as it just sleeps while checking with a backoff. The performance problems would completely be limited to the sync commit waits.